# Numbers on the blackboard: From 2-2015 to 1-2014

Tags: mathematics, reachability, blackboard

The numbers $ 2, \ldots, 2015 $ are written on a blackboard. Each minute any two numbers $ x $ and  $ y $
are wiped out and are replaced by two  numbers $\displaystyle \frac { 4x + 3y } { 5 }  $ and  $\displaystyle \frac { 24x - 7y } { 25 }  $.

Is it possible that after some time the numbers $ 1, \ldots, 2014 $ are written on the blackboard ?

Comment: I assume that $(3,4,5)$ and $(7,24,25)$ being [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) has something to do with the solution...

Comment: Also possibly relevant: $(\frac{4i+3}{5})^2=\frac{24i-7}{25}$

Comment: Are we assuming all the numbers are integers? Do fractions get written up, or are they rounded?

Comment: $14(\frac{4x+3y}{5})^2+25(\frac{24x-7y}{25})^2=32x^2+7y^2$

Comment: and $14+25=32+7$

Comment: So aim is removing 2015 and try to produce 1 and reproduce other numbers that wiped out in the process.

Comment: Can _x_ equal _y_ ?

Comment: @Haobin Do you know the answer?

Comment: @Matthew0898 As he hasn't stated that as not allowed, I assume it is allowed.

Comment: I have noticed that for the values $y =2x, y = \frac{x}3, y = \frac{3x}4$, you will always reproduce one of your inputs (e.g. $5,10 \rightarrow 10,2$ or $15,5 \rightarrow 15,13$ or $4,3 \rightarrow 5,3$).  These are the only values for which this is true.  I'm not sure if this has any relevance, but it is an interesting observation.

Answer (score 14):

### Answer

> Yes it is possible.

### The (maybe) interesting details

> I started by creating a huge HTML table containing an overview of the generated values (right click the image and select "View image" for bigger version):
> [image: table]
> I ignored non integer values, therefore most of the fields are empty. The integer values form a regular pattern. The highlighted fields are the ones which keep one of the values unchanged. In addition to the 3 variants mentioned by **GentlePurpleRain** above, there is one more which uses negative values.
> Using a highlighted red field it's possible to increase a single value while keeping the other unchanged. Using a highlighted blue field allows to decrease a single value. However, this is not enough to solve the puzzle. The next step was to increase the complexity. Look at the field representing [6, 17] -> [15, 1]. This changes two values, but we can restore one of them in a second step, namely [15 30] -> [30 6]. The effect of both these replacements is [17] -> [1].
> There are more possibilities, e.g. [255, 510] -> [510, 102] and [102, 289] -> [255, 17] result in [289] -> [17]. Together with the previous combination we have [289] -> [1].
> This can be continued further, which I have done using a computer program. It starts with the highlighted fields, and in each iteration adds more possible single number transformations to the list, until it finds the transformation [2015] -> [1]. See next chapter for the result.

### The ugly details

> Here is a possible sequence. It's not necessarily the shortest one, it's the one which was easiest to find.
>  `Replacement                 Surplus               Missing`
>  `.                           [2015]                [1]`
>  `[300, 100] -> [300, 260]    [260, 2015]           [1, 100]`
>  `[180, 260] -> [300, 100]    [300, 2015]           [1, 180]`
>  `[300, 600] -> [600, 120]    [120, 2015]           [1, 180]`
>  `[135, 120] -> [180, 96]     [96, 2015]            [1, 135]`
>  `[96, 97] -> [135, 65]       [65, 2015]            [1, 97]`
>  `[120, 65] -> [135, 97]      [135, 2015]           [1, 120]`
>  `[96, 72] -> [120, 72]       [135, 2015]           [1, 96]`
>  `[135, 120] -> [180, 96]     [180, 2015]           [1, 120]`
>  `[252, 189] -> [315, 189]    [180, 315, 2015]      [1, 120, 252]`
>  `[315, 180] -> [360, 252]    [360, 2015]           [1, 120]`
>  `[360, 720] -> [720, 144]    [144, 2015]           [1, 120]`
>  `[167, 144] -> [220, 120]    [220, 2015]           [1, 167]`
>  `[308, 231] -> [385, 231]    [220, 385, 2015]      [1, 167, 308]`
>  `[385, 220] -> [440, 308]    [440, 2015]           [1, 167]`
>  `[440, 880] -> [880, 176]    [176, 2015]           [1, 167]`
>  `[176, 7] -> [145, 167]      [145, 2015]           [1, 7]`
>  `[375, 750] -> [750, 150]    [145, 150, 2015]      [1, 7, 375]`
>  `[150, 425] -> [375, 25]     [25, 145, 2015]       [1, 7, 425]`
>  `[450, 25] -> [375, 425]     [145, 375, 2015]      [1, 7, 450]`
>  `[375, 250] -> [450, 290]    [145, 290, 2015]      [1, 7, 250]`
>  `[290, 30] -> [250, 270]     [145, 270, 2015]      [1, 7, 30]`
>  `[225, 450] -> [450, 90]     [90, 145, 270, 2015]  [1, 7, 30, 225]`
>  `[90, 255] -> [225, 15]      [15, 145, 270, 2015]  [1, 7, 30, 255]`
>  `[270, 15] -> [225, 255]     [145, 225, 2015]      [1, 7, 30]`
>  `[225, 450] -> [450, 90]     [90, 145, 2015]       [1, 7, 30]`
>  `[270, 90] -> [270, 234]     [145, 234, 2015]      [1, 7, 30]`
>  `[390, 130] -> [390, 338]    [145, 234, 338, 2015] [1, 7, 30, 130]`
>  `[234, 338] -> [390, 130]    [145, 390, 2015]      [1, 7, 30]`
>  `[145, 390] -> [350, 30]     [350, 2015]           [1, 7]`
>  `[315, 105] -> [315, 273]    [273, 350, 2015]      [1, 7, 105]`
>  `[189, 273] -> [315, 105]    [315, 350, 2015]      [1, 7, 189]`
>  `[224, 168] -> [280, 168]    [280, 315, 350, 2015] [1, 7, 189, 224]`
>  `[315, 280] -> [420, 224]    [350, 420, 2015]      [1, 7, 189]`
>  `[420, 315] -> [525, 315]    [350, 525, 2015]      [1, 7, 189]`
>  `[350, 525] -> [595, 189]    [595, 2015]           [1, 7]`
>  `[595, 2015] -> [1685, 7]    [1685]                [1]`
>  `[60, 20] -> [60, 52]        [52, 1685]            [1, 20]`
>  `[36, 52] -> [60, 20]        [60, 1685]            [1, 36]`
>  `[55, 60] -> [80, 36]        [80, 1685]            [1, 55]`
>  `[112, 84] -> [140, 84]      [80, 140, 1685]       [1, 55, 112]`
>  `[140, 80] -> [160, 112]     [160, 1685]           [1, 55]`
>  `[160, 320] -> [320, 64]     [64, 1685]            [1, 55]`
>  `[64, 23] -> [65, 55]        [65, 1685]            [1, 23]`
>  `[65, 130] -> [130, 26]      [26, 1685]            [1, 23]`
>  `[26, 7] -> [25, 23]         [25, 1685]            [1, 7]`
>  `[120, 40] -> [120, 104]     [25, 104, 1685]       [1, 7, 40]`
>  `[72, 104] -> [120, 40]      [25, 120, 1685]       [1, 7, 72]`
>  `[120, 240] -> [240, 48]     [25, 48, 1685]        [1, 7, 72]`
>  `[89, 48] -> [100, 72]       [25, 100, 1685]       [1, 7, 89]`
>  `[100, 25] -> [95, 89]       [95, 1685]            [1, 7]`
>  `[35, 95] -> [85, 7]         [85, 1685]            [1, 35]`
>  `[85, 170] -> [170, 34]      [34, 1685]            [1, 35]`
>  `[34, 13] -> [35, 29]        [29, 1685]            [1, 13]`
>  `[168, 126] -> [210, 126]    [29, 210, 1685]       [1, 13, 168]`
>  `[210, 120] -> [240, 168]    [29, 240, 1685]       [1, 13, 120]`
>  `[336, 252] -> [420, 252]    [29, 240, 420, 1685]  [1, 13, 120, 336]`
>  `[420, 240] -> [480, 336]    [29, 480, 1685]       [1, 13, 120]`
>  `[480, 960] -> [960, 192]    [29, 192, 1685]       [1, 13, 120]`
>  `[181, 192] -> [260, 120]    [29, 260, 1685]       [1, 13, 181]`
>  `[500, 1000] -> [1000, 200]  [29, 200, 260, 1685]  [1, 13, 181, 500]`
>  `[475, 200] -> [500, 400]    [29, 260, 400, 1685]  [1, 13, 181, 475]`
>  `[400, 300] -> [500, 300]    [29, 260, 500, 1685]  [1, 13, 181, 475]`
>  `[500, 125] -> [475, 445]    [29, 260, 445, 1685]  [1, 13, 125, 181]`
>  `[260, 445] -> [475, 125]    [29, 475, 1685]       [1, 13, 181]`
>  `[525, 175] -> [525, 455]    [29, 455, 475, 1685]  [1, 13, 175, 181]`
>  `[455, 935] -> [925, 175]    [29, 475, 925, 1685]  [1, 13, 181, 935]`
>  `[475, 925] -> [935, 197]    [29, 197, 1685]       [1, 13, 181]`
>  `[197, 29] -> [175, 181]     [175, 1685]           [1, 13]`
>  `[256, 192] -> [320, 192]    [175, 320, 1685]      [1, 13, 256]`
>  `[360, 320] -> [480, 256]    [175, 480, 1685]      [1, 13, 360]`
>  `[480, 960] -> [960, 192]    [175, 192, 1685]      [1, 13, 360]`
>  `[431, 192] -> [460, 360]    [175, 460, 1685]      [1, 13, 431]`
>  `[196, 147] -> [245, 147]    [175, 245, 460, 1685] [1, 13, 196, 431]`
>  `[245, 140] -> [280, 196]    [175, 280, 460, 1685] [1, 13, 140, 431]`
>  `[280, 460] -> [500, 140]    [175, 500, 1685]      [1, 13, 431]`
>  `[500, 175] -> [505, 431]    [505, 1685]           [1, 13]`
>  `[505, 1685] -> [1415, 13]   [1415]                [1]`
>  `[600, 200] -> [600, 520]    [520, 1415]           [1, 200]`
>  `[360, 520] -> [600, 200]    [600, 1415]           [1, 360]`
>  `[600, 1200] -> [1200, 240]  [240, 1415]           [1, 360]`
>  `[445, 240] -> [500, 360]    [500, 1415]           [1, 445]`
>  `[500, 75] -> [445, 459]     [459, 1415]           [1, 75]`
>  `[405, 810] -> [810, 162]    [162, 459, 1415]      [1, 75, 405]`
>  `[162, 459] -> [405, 27]     [27, 1415]            [1, 75]`
>  `[86, 27] -> [85, 75]        [85, 1415]            [1, 86]`
>  `[75, 150] -> [150, 30]      [30, 85, 1415]        [1, 75, 86]`
>  `[30, 85] -> [75, 5]         [5, 1415]             [1, 86]`
>  `[140, 280] -> [280, 56]     [5, 56, 1415]         [1, 86, 140]`
>  `[133, 56] -> [140, 112]     [5, 112, 1415]        [1, 86, 133]`
>  `[112, 84] -> [140, 84]      [5, 140, 1415]        [1, 86, 133]`
>  `[140, 5] -> [115, 133]      [115, 1415]           [1, 86]`
>  `[115, 230] -> [230, 46]     [46, 1415]            [1, 86]`
>  `[103, 46] -> [110, 86]      [110, 1415]           [1, 103]`
>  `[280, 210] -> [350, 210]    [110, 350, 1415]      [1, 103, 280]`
>  `[350, 200] -> [400, 280]    [110, 400, 1415]      [1, 103, 200]`
>  `[400, 800] -> [800, 160]    [110, 160, 1415]      [1, 103, 200]`
>  `[130, 160] -> [200, 80]     [80, 110, 1415]       [1, 103, 130]`
>  `[80, 110] -> [130, 46]      [46, 1415]            [1, 103]`
>  `[120, 40] -> [120, 104]     [46, 104, 1415]       [1, 40, 103]`
>  `[72, 104] -> [120, 40]      [46, 120, 1415]       [1, 72, 103]`
>  `[110, 120] -> [160, 72]     [46, 160, 1415]       [1, 103, 110]`
>  `[224, 168] -> [280, 168]    [46, 160, 280, 1415]  [1, 103, 110, 224]`
>  `[280, 160] -> [320, 224]    [46, 320, 1415]       [1, 103, 110]`
>  `[320, 640] -> [640, 128]    [46, 128, 1415]       [1, 103, 110]`
>  `[128, 46] -> [130, 110]     [130, 1415]           [1, 103]`
>  `[112, 84] -> [140, 84]      [130, 140, 1415]      [1, 103, 112]`
>  `[140, 80] -> [160, 112]     [130, 160, 1415]      [1, 80, 103]`
>  `[130, 160] -> [200, 80]     [200, 1415]           [1, 103]`
>  `[600, 200] -> [600, 520]    [520, 1415]           [1, 103]`
>  `[520, 1415] -> [1265, 103]  [1265]                [1]`
>  `[120, 40] -> [120, 104]     [104, 1265]           [1, 40]`
>  `[72, 104] -> [120, 40]      [120, 1265]           [1, 72]`
>  `[168, 126] -> [210, 126]    [120, 210, 1265]      [1, 72, 168]`
>  `[210, 120] -> [240, 168]    [240, 1265]           [1, 72]`
>  `[145, 240] -> [260, 72]     [260, 1265]           [1, 145]`
>  `[364, 273] -> [455, 273]    [260, 455, 1265]      [1, 145, 364]`
>  `[455, 260] -> [520, 364]    [520, 1265]           [1, 145]`
>  `[520, 1265] -> [1175, 145]  [1175]                [1]`
>  `[750, 1500] -> [1500, 300]  [300, 1175]           [1, 750]`
>  `[300, 850] -> [750, 50]     [50, 1175]            [1, 850]`
>  `[900, 50] -> [750, 850]     [750, 1175]           [1, 900]`
>  `[750, 1500] -> [1500, 300]  [300, 1175]           [1, 900]`
>  `[1025, 300] -> [1000, 900]  [1000, 1175]          [1, 1025]`
>  `[1000, 2000] -> [2000, 400] [400, 1175]           [1, 1025]`
>  `[400, 1175] -> [1025, 55]   [55]                  [1]`
>  `[300, 600] -> [600, 120]    [55, 120]             [1, 300]`
>  `[285, 120] -> [300, 240]    [55, 240]             [1, 285]`
>  `[240, 155] -> [285, 187]    [55, 187]             [1, 155]`
>  `[105, 35] -> [105, 91]      [55, 91, 187]         [1, 35, 155]`
>  `[91, 187] -> [185, 35]      [55, 185]             [1, 155]`
>  `[55, 185] -> [155, 1]       []                    []`

Comment: This is long and I didn't check everything, but the first few are correct. To be honest I am pretty surprised that the answer is yes.

Comment: Congratulations!  I will award the bounty as soon as I verify your solution.  @Haobin, did you know there was a solution when you posted the question?  Is this similar to your own solution?  I'd be very interested in reading any mathematical explanation of why those two particular equations were chosen for the problem, and whether there is a mathematical proof showing how this can be done.

Comment: @Sleafar Dammit, I had a very similar idea but you beat me to it :-) Nicely done!

Answer (score -2):

I believe that **no**.

For many pairs of numbers `x` and `y`, `(4x + 3y) / 5` and `(24x − 7y) / 25` won't even be integers. For example:

```
x = 2, y = 7: 
   (4x + 3y) / 5 = (8 + 21) / 5 = 29/5 = 5.8
   (24x − 7y) / 25 = (48 - 49) / 25 = -1/25 = -0.04
```

In about only 1/5 of the steps the first expression will be an integer, and in about only 1/25 of the steps the second expression will be an integer, per divisibility rules, and assuming that the numerator is a random integer.

And, by construction, most non-integer numbers will continue to be operated into other non-integer numbers - with bigger denominators in fractional form.

The question can be turned around into: Find a way to generate all numbers from 1 to 2014, given the operations with `x` and `y` above, and choosing `x` and `y` for each step. Expecting it to happen at random is extremely improbable.

Comment: I don't think anyone is expecting it to happen at random.  The question asks, "is it possible?".  Thus if there is *any* possible selection of numbers that leads to the sequence $1...2014$, the answer is "Yes."  Indicating that it won't likely happen randomly is stating the obvious.